# Scikit-Learn: GridSearchCV With Surprising Output After .Fit()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm using `xgboost` and `sklearn` for a Kaggle competition (https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques#evaluation).

Specifically, I'm using `GridSearchCV` to try out different hyperparameters for my `XGBRegressor` model.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk
import matplotlib as plt
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100

xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
params = {"max_depth": [3, 4], "learning_rate": [0.05],
         "n_estimators": [1000, 2000], "n_jobs": [8], "subsample": [0.8], "random_state": [42]}
grid_search_cv = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, params, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error",
                             n_jobs=8, cv=KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42), verbose=2)

grid_search_cv.fit(X, y)
```

So I'm trying out some `max_depth`, `learning_rate`, `n_estimators`, etc.

Strangely, calling `.fit()` above results in this output:

```
GridSearchCV(cv=KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=True),
       error_score='raise',
       estimator=XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0,
       max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100,
       n_jobs=1, nthread=None, objective='reg:linear', random_state=0,
       reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
       silent=True, subsample=1),
       fit_params=None, iid=True, n_jobs=8,
       param_grid={'max_depth': [3, 4], 'learning_rate': [0.05], 'n_estimators': [1000, 2000], 'n_jobs': [8], 'subsample': [0.8], 'random_state': [42]},
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', verbose=2)
```

So `GridSearchCV` outputs itself but with an `XGBRegressor` instance using hyperparameter values I didn't specify?

Looks like those are the defaults but I can't find `.fit()` in the `sklearn` docs (only `.fit_params`)...

Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Did you notice that the last 3-4 lines of the output contain the parameters that you have specified? Perhaps, what is happening is that the name of the estimator object gets listed first along with the default conditions and then come the custom parameter values.

Comment: @KRKirov Thats exactly what happens. `fit()` returns self. @bclayman if you want the best hyperparameters then use `grid_search_cv.best_params_` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @VivekKumar.